# VAKCR Table on S/4HANA

Tags: abap, s4hana

How can I read VAKCR table data (Sales Index: Orders in Credit Management)  which does not exist on S/4HANA using SQLScript?

I have to convert an ABAP code block where data is queried from VAKCR table.
Since this table is removed on S4, I cannot read it directly from VAKCR index table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I check SAP Note 2217124 as @Gert pointed, I see a ABAP report named **VAKCR_REBUILD** and note that there is a view named v_vmvah which can be used instead of vakcr table

Or following code could be used

```
SELECT * FROM vbak
WHERE vbeln IN s_vbeln    AND
"vbobj EQ 'A'        AND
gbstk IN ('A', 'B') AND
cmgst IN ('B', 'D').
```

Comment: Cool! They must have updated the note or you are better at reading them, glad it's cleared up, I suspect I will bump into the same issue soon.

Answer (score 2):

For the Credit Management processes in SAP S/4HANA, please refer to SAP Note '2217124 -  S/4 HANA: Credit Management Changes in SD'. Not that the note gives much information. This just seems to be the state of a transformation to S/4HANA at the moment. My suggestion to you is to open a message to SAP.